# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS after calling res.redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have below code to redirect http traffic to https but it is giving   ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

any reason ? How we can fix it in node js?

```
 module.exports = [
    '/',
    (req, res, next) => {
        if (req.hostname !== 'localhost' && req.protocol === 'http') {
            let url = 'https://' + req.headers.host + req.url;
            res.redirect(url);
        } else {
            next();
        }
    },
];
```

Note : value of req.protocol is always returning http for https requests on server.

I hit https url and checked req.protocol value and it was http

Comment: Perhaps you have a reverse proxy / load balancer in front of your application which handles SSL termination, so the connection to your backend is HTTP even when from a client's perspective it is HTTPS? In this case you would need to make sure the reverse proxy / load balancer adds some header with the original protocol (this is often already the case - check `X-Forwarded-Proto` for example, or `CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto` for CloudFront) and then you need to check this header in a middleware and update your `req.protocol` accordingly so the code can work.

Comment: Any idea where and how to set X-Forwarded-Proto  ?

Comment: Depends on which server you have in the middle and how it's configured. I can't tell you without knowing that

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to debug it, to know the following:

- Do you enter in the if statement
- If yes, what are the values for req.protocol and req.hostname, for the first iteration, and for the next one(s), to see if these are the values you are expected for

Comment: req.protocol always getting value http for https url. any reason?

Comment: See my comment above. Probably you have some other server in front of yours that handles SSL termination.

Comment: Can we stop SSL termination through our application ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of redirecting the HTTP traffic to HTTPS by using the Nodejs code. I'd prefer you to configure the redirect directly inside your webserver ***Apache*** or ***Nginx*** and You can also use Cloudflare if you don't have ***Apache*** or ***Nginx*** access on your server. And also you are facing this problem because you are maybe redirecting visitors multiple times. For example, I think you are already redirecting traffic via webserver, and after you are again redirecting via the code. So, I'd prefer you to remove this middleware.